# Joining tags table to posts table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tags

I need some help retrieving posts that belong to a specific group of tags. I am working with Codeigniter and MySQL.

My tables look like this:

**posts** - postid, title, date, etc

**tags** - tagid, tag

**post_tags** - postid, tagid

This is the function I am using in my model:

```
function get_posts($tags) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'DESC');
    $this->db->join('post_tags', 'posts.postid = post_tags.postid');
    $this->db->join('tags', 'post_tags.tagid = tags.tagid');
    $this->db->where_in('tags.tag', $tags);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

So far, the query is working the way I want and returning all the proper posts.

However, while looping through the result and setting up the specific post information, only the *first tag* is being listed per post.

Is it possible to restucture the query so that each post includes *all* the tags that match the original $tags array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but I think you need to add a join type to the query:

```
function get_posts($tags) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'DESC');
    $this->db->join('post_tags', 'posts.postid = post_tags.postid');

    // add the "right" keyword to produce a RIGHT JOIN
    $this->db->join('tags', 'post_tags.tagid = tags.tagid', 'right'); 

    $this->db->where_in('tags.tag', $tags);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result();
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: This is producing the exact same result.

Comment: What is the query being generated? You might try a few separate keywords:  `left inner`, `left outer`, `right inner`, or `right outer`.

Comment: Also, if you're not too far in your application to start with, you might take a look at using an ORM. I use Datamapper ORM (http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) and this query would be this easy:  `$posts->include_related('tag', 'tags')->order_by('date', 'DESC')->get();`

Comment: I have tried every type of join, yet the post array data comes back exactly the same every time.

Comment: Can you post the actual query being generated?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (`posts`) JOIN `post_tags` ON `posts`.`postid` = `post_tags`.`postid` JOIN `tags` ON `post_tags`.`tagid` = `tags`.`tagid` WHERE `type` = 'post' AND `tags`.`tag` IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3') GROUP BY `posts`.`postid` ORDER BY `date` DESC

Comment: Take a look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195627/codeigniter-active-record-sql-complex-join), not exactly the same issue, but might help